# Laravel middleware not redirecting to custom login page

Tags: laravel

I have two middlewares set up for admin and one for customer

```
class AuthenticateCustomer
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (! Auth::guard('customer')->check()) {
           return redirect(route('customer.login'));
       }
       return $next($request);
   }
 }
```

And that of the admin is

```
class AuthenticateAdmin
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if (! Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
           return redirect(route('admin.login'));
       }
       return $next($request);
   }
}
```

However I still get directed to the Laravel built in log in page auth.login. It appears my middlewares are not being used.

Answer (score 1):

did you config auth.php? if not then config auth.php. Open **config/auth.php** and add the new guards edit as follows:

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    */
    //For User

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        //For Admin

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

      'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
```

You can also modify **LoginController** if you want to use same controller, then opent the Login Controller in **app/Http/Controllers/Auth** and edit as follows:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        [...]
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
            $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
        }
        [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an alias for you middleware in `app\http\Kernel.php` like below:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'customerAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateCustomer::class,
    'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin::class,
]
```

Then use it on your routes like below as group:

```
// For customer
Route::group(['middleware' => 'customerAuth'],function (){
    Route::get('test',function (){
        
    });
});

// For admin
Route::group(['middleware' => 'adminAuth'],function (){
    Route::get('test',function (){
        
    });
});
```

Comment: I have done all the above however I have this in my controllers that deal with my respective users...

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth:customer');
  }


I have a feeling the middleware name I am using is incorrect...

Comment: Finally solved it, I was using the wrong middleware name...Thanks. Needed to be 'admin_auth' and 'customer_auth' respectively